# R- Display value with aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe in R with the following variables:

```
DateTime year dayYear diameter dendro
```

I want to calculate the min diameter for each day of the year for each dendrometer, so I used aggregate:

```
dailymin <- aggregate(diameter~year+dayYear+dendro, FUN=min, data=myData)
```

However, I also need the time when the min diameter happened at each day and dendro. Therefore, I need to keep the info contained in the variable DateTime in the row of each min.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe look into `which.min`, and if you want the last one, maybe `FUN = function(x) tail(which.min(x),1)`. These would be expressed in row numbers, so then... `myData[result,]`.

Answer (score 0):

You may alternatively use the [plyr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) for this purpose and add a new column by the transform shortcut function:

```
ddply(myData, .(variables.list), transform, new.variable= min(diameter))
```

Comment: If there are several min for each day, how can I only select the one that happened further in time (in format POSIXct in the variable DateTime)??

Comment: @CesarTerrer, that's a different question. Consider making a new post.